# iOS Keyboard inadvertently changes layout

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, keyboard

My environment:
Xcode 6.1.1 on a Mac running under OSX Yosemite 10.10.2 coding for target iphone 5:

Using the IB, I have configured my textfields for a standard keyboard with default appearance and return key=Done. This works fine. Then I added a button with the following event routine:

```
- (IBAction)siteNeu:(id)sender {
_keyText.text = @"newkey";
_siteData.text = @"latitude, longitude, altitude";
[oldkey setString:_keyText.text];
[olddata setString:_siteData.text];
[mysitedata extendAndSaveDictionary:_keyText.text associatedValue: _siteData.text];
[_keyText becomeFirstResponder];
```

}

When clicking this button, the keyboard shows, but with a different layout. No numbers, no return key and no done key. What's going wrong here?

Comment: adding code that assigns 
_keyText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault and _keyText.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone 
does not help. Actually, the keyboard that pops up shows a layout that I can find nowhere in apples documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be calling **becomeFirstResponder method** on UITextField other then the one, which you configured from IB, Check your textField Outlets to make sure that it's the same one which you have configured.

I have tested your scenario it work fine with the same textfield. If you want to show same keyboard on other textfields you have to configure all the textfield from IB.

Comment: You have a point: I changed the references to _keyText to self.keyText and then it works. I thought that _keyText is just a shorter name for self.keyText. Obviously I am wrong about this.